# Retrieve data from my database and send it as an email using SendGrid in Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sendgrid

I am a beginner and I am building my first web application. I will use SendGrid API to send emails to users. I already created an account on SendGrid and imported everything that I need and also already tested sending an email. It is working! Now I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I am going to retrieve data from my database and use SendGrid to send the email. I am using Python and my database is on Model.py (I am using postgresql).

Does anyone have any thoughts to help me?

Code in model.py:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class User(db.Model):
    """A user."""

    __tablename__ = "users"

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String)
    lname = db.Column(db.String)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String)
    photo = db.Column(db.String)

    letters = db.relationship("Letter", back_populates="user")
    favorites = db.relationship("Letter", secondary="favorites", back_populates="user")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        """Show info about user."""

        return f'<User user_id={self.user_id} email={self.email}>'

class Letter(db.Model):
    """A letter."""

    __tablename__ = "letters"

    letter_id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    letter_title = db.Column(db.String)
    letter_body = db.Column(db.String)
    creation_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    delivery_date = db.Column(db.Date)
    likes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    read = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    publish = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.user_id"))

    # create a relationship
    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="letters")
    
    def __repr__(self):
        """Show info about letter."""

        return f'<Letter letter_id={self.letter_id} letter_title={self.letter_title}>'



"""This is my server.py (this is just one of my routes)"""

from flask import (Flask, render_template, request, flash, 
                                        session, redirect)
import random                  

from model import connect_to_db, db
import crud
from jinja2 import StrictUndefined
import os
import cloudinary.uploader

CLOUDINARY_KEY = os.environ['CLOUDINARY_KEY']
CLOUDINARY_SECRET = os.environ['CLOUDINARY_SECRET']
CLOUD_NAME = "dnw3idclo"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "dev"
app.jinja_env.undefined = StrictUndefined

@app.route("/registration", methods=["POST"])
def create_user():
    """Create a user account."""

    fname = request.form.get("fname")
    lname = request.form.get("lname")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    password = request.form.get("password")
    photo = request.files['my-file']
    
    response= send_user_profile_pic(photo)
    
    if 'secure_url' in response:
        photo_url = response['secure_url']
    else:
        photo_url = ""
    
    user = crud.get_user_by_email(email)
    if user:
        flash("You cannot create an account with that email. Please try again.")
    else:
        user = crud.create_user(fname=fname, lname=lname, email=email, password=password, photo=photo_url)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Account created succesfully! Please log in.")


"""Also use crud functions to query data from my data base:"""

from model import db, User, Letter, Favorite, connect_to_db


def create_user(fname, lname, email, password, photo):
    """Create user's account."""

    user_account = User(fname=fname, lname=lname, email=email, password=password, photo=photo)
    

    return user_account

def get_user_by_email(email):
    """Return a user by email."""

    return User.query.filter(User.email == email).first()

def get_user_by_id(user_id):

    return User.query.get(user_id)

def create_letter_for_user(letter_title, letter_body, creation_date, delivery_date, likes, read, publish, user_id):
    """Create letter for users."""

    letter = Letter(
        letter_title=letter_title,
        letter_body=letter_body,
        creation_date=creation_date,
        delivery_date=delivery_date, 
        likes=likes,
        read=read, 
        publish=publish,
        user_id=user_id)

    return letter    

"""And finally is my file for SendGrid:"""

import sendgrid
import os
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail, Email, To, Content
from model import connect_to_db, db
import crud
from flask import (Flask, render_template, redirect, session,
                           request,)
from jinja2 import StrictUndefined

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "dev"
app.jinja_env.undefined = StrictUndefined
# import model, crud, server, flask

sg = sendgrid.SendGridAPIClient(api_key=os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY'))
from_email = Email("sender.test@gmail.com")  # changed to my verified sender
to_email = To("receiver.test@gmail.com")  # the recipient that I want to send the email
subject = "Letter to Your Future Self"
content = Content("text/plain", "Test, test, test and more test")
mail = Mail(from_email, to_email, subject, content)

# Get a JSON-ready representation of the Mail object
mail_json = mail.get()

# Send an HTTP POST request to /mail/send
response = sg.client.mail.send.post(request_body=mail_json)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that'll help us understand what issue you are facing with your code.

Comment: You might not want to share any personal information (such as your email address) publicly. You could define a dummy variable such as `email = "xyz@gmail.com"` and use that in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed it. I didn't realize that I had sent my personal info.